# Error sending SMS to SIM900 in PIC

Tags: pic, c, at-commands, sim900

I am trying to interface `SIM900` with `PIC18F2520`. I need to send SMS to a particular cell number. According to AT commands, `AT+CMGS="number"` is used to send SMS. After sending this command, we have to write our message and then press Ctrl+Z to terminate it. SIM 900 will then send the SMS.

I am doing the same thing as above but not able to send SMS. Following is the code:

```
putrsUSART("AT+CMGS=\"96********\"\r);   //command with number
putrsUSART("Hello");    //message content
putrsUSART("0x1A");     /to terminate it
```

but after sending these commands I am not receiving any SMS. I am confused with how to send `0x1A` to SIM900. How to actually send hex numbers via UART?

**Edit:**

I am able to send sms but the sms is empty. I have attached a image of the response:

[image]

Comment: To put 0x1A into a string you use an escape sequence like this putrsUSART("\x1A");

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that "AT+CMGS=\"96********\"\r makes any sense. Surely it should be "AT+CMGS=96*****\r"

Comment: @SteveG I have included `("\x1A") and now I am able to send sms but the problem it doesnt have any text. I mean empty SMS.

Comment: What is the response or error code from the SIM900?

Comment: @SteveG I have attached an image of the response

Comment: I'm thinking that you have one <CR> too many, try removing the \r from the AT+CMGS command. It looks like that the putrsUSART function adds <CR><LF> to the end of each string.

Comment: In your code, after sending the phone number to the SIM900, you have to wait until it processes it an returns `>`. Also you are sending the `0x1A` as a string, but it is an ASCII character code, it should be sent as an simple character, aka as a hexadecimal value (if you have a function to send a single char via UART, then you should use that like `putChar(0x1A)`). I think thats why your code does not work. Regarding the empty SMS, check the SMS format settings as well, maybe you are not in text mode but PDU.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I am in the text mode. I am sending `AT+CMGF=1` before sms command

Comment: On your image, the 4th line is when you press Ctrl+Z?

Comment: @BenceKaulics I have solved the issue. Actually I was using PIC18 libraries so I was using `putrsUSART()` function to send data serially and this function adds a NULL before the data. So due to this, it was not accepting any message content. I modified it and made my own function. So now I am receiving message with its content too.!

Comment: Then please post the modified code with this explanation as an answer. It will be useful for others, you will be able to accept this answer as well.